# Deleting two specific Characters

Tags: c++

So I have a little problem, I want to achieve this in C++, but I don't know how to do it:

Given is a string containing random numbers, symbols, and letters:

```
std::string = "1653gbdtsr362g2v3f3t52bv^hdtvsbjj;hdfuue,9^1dkkns";
```

Now I'm trying to find all `^` characters, and if those are followed by a number between 0 and 9, delete the `^` and the number, so:

```
"^1ghhu^7dndn^g"
```

becomes:

```
"ghhudndn^g"
```

I know how to find and replace/erase chars from a string, but I don't know how to check if it's followed by a number in a not hard coded way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to try and solve the problem yourself. Else, you won't get good responses and it will be considered as a homework and that you are trying to cheat. You are on the wrong website if you don't have codes and erros and this will get downvoted

Comment: its not a homework and i can provide the coding i tried, but i didnt knew why i should post it if it doesnt work and i dont get any errors, because i dont know how to achiev and what i tried doesnt gives errors so idc

Comment: Just post it and mention it as your attempt, this will get you better responses. I will help you solve the problem

Comment: If you can find the '^', then looking at the next character and testing if it's a digit should be trivial (`std::isdigit`), as should removing two characters from a known location in the string(`std::string::erase`).

Comment: well that was helpful, thank you user

Comment: "Why I should post it if it doesn't work" -- so we can point out to you what you did wrong, and you'll learn from that. You don't learn anything by just getting someone else to write it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

template<class Iter, class OutIter>
OutIter remove_escaped_numbers(Iter first, Iter last, OutIter out) {
    for ( ; first != last ; )
    {
        auto c = *first++;
        if (c == '^' && first != last)
        {
            c = *first++;
            if (std::isdigit(c))
                continue;
            else {
                *out++ = '^';
                *out++ = c;
            }
        }
        else {
            *out++ = c;
        }
    }
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    auto input = "^1ghhu^7dndn^g"s;
    auto output = std::string{};

    remove_escaped_numbers(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(output));

    std::cout << output << std::endl;
}
```

or this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>



int main()
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    auto input = "^1ghhu^7dndn^g"s;

    static const auto repl = std::regex  { R"___(\^\d)___" };
    auto output = std::regex_replace(input, repl, "");
    std::cout << output << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string s = "^1ghhu^7dndn^g";
for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - 1; ++i)
{
    if (s[i] == '^' && std::isdigit(s[i + 1]))
    {
        s.erase(i, 2);
        --i;
    }
}
```

This needs these includes:

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
```

Comment: Not the fastest way to do this, but has the advantage of being dead simple and easy to read. One suggestion: instead of `--i`, use a `while (i < s.length()-1)` and increment `i` if you didn't erase.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using std::stringstream, and returning the input string cleared of caret-digit's.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>

int t404()
{
   std::stringstream ss;

   std::string inStr("1653gbdtsr362g2v3f3t52bv^hdtvsbjj;hdfuue,9^1dkkns");

   for (size_t i = 0; i<inStr.size(); ++i)
   {
      if(('^' == inStr[i]) &&  isdigit(inStr[i+1]))
      {
         i += 1; // skip over caret followed by single digit
      }
      else
      {
         ss << inStr[i];
      }
    }
   std::cout << inStr << std::endl;      // compare input
   std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;   // to results
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 1653gbdtsr362g2v3f3t52bv^hdtvsbjj;hdfuue,9^1dkkns
>   1653gbdtsr362g2v3f3t52bv^hdtvsbjj;hdfuue,9dkkns

Comment: Loving this: `'^' == inStr[i]`. one of the best, simplest defenses against typo-induced bugs in the C-like programming worlds.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply loop over the string and copy it while skipping the undesired chars. Here is a possible function to do it:

```
std::string filterString (std::string& s) {
    std::string result = "";
    std::string::iterator it = s.begin();
    char c; 
    while (it != s.end()) {
        if (*it == '^' && it != s.end() && (it + 1) != s.end()) {
            c = *(it + 1);
            if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
                it += 2;
                continue;
            }
        }
        result.push_back(*it);
        ++ it;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A robust solution would be to use the [regex library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) that C++11 brings in.

```
std::string input ("1653gbdtsr362g2v3f3t52bv^hdtvsbjj;hdfuue,9^1dkkns");
std::regex rx ("[\\^][\\d]{1}");  // "[\^][\d]{1}"
std::cout << std::regex_replace(input,rx,"woot");

>> 1653gbdtsr362g2v3f3t52bv^hdtvsbjj;hdfuue,9wootdkkns
```

This locates a "^" character (`[\^]`) followed by 1 (`{1}`) digit (`[\d]`) and replaces all occurances with `"woot"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code can solve your problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

    int main() 
{
    std::string str = "^1ghhu^7dndn^g";
    std::string::iterator first, last;
    for ( std::string::iterator it=str.begin(); it!=str.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it == '^') 
        {
            first = it;
            it++;
            while(isdigit(*it))
            {
                it++;
            }
            last = it - 1;
            if(first != last)
            {
                if((last + 1) != str.end()) 
                {
                    str.erase(first, last + 1);
                }
                else    
                {
                    str.erase(first, str.end());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout<< str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

```
$ ./erase 
ghhudndn^g
```